# Show for different values of $a, b$ that an equation system has infinite, no or a unique solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with this question:

show that for different values of $a, b$ that the following equation system has infinite, no or a unique solution. Set the parameters $a, b \in R$ so that the equation system has no solutions.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 &+& ax_2 &+& x_3 &=& 0\\
    x_1 &+& (a+1)x_2 &+&x_3 &=& 0\\
    3x_1 &+& (3a+2)x_2 &+&a^2x_3 &=& b\\
  \end{bmatrix} $$

By using using gaussian elimination i get:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 &+& ax_2 &+& x_3 &=& 0\\
      &+&  x_2 &+& &=& 0\\
      &+&   &+&(a^2-5)x_3 &=& b\\
  \end{bmatrix} $$

Can anyone please help me with moving forward on this?

Comment: What if the third row gave the equation $0=1$? What if it gave $x_3=1$? What if it gave $0=0$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think I am getting it :) By the way, is there a good application for writing these kind of matrices?

Comment: What do they mean with set the parameters $b∈R$ so that the equation system has no solutions btw? Is that the $a=sqrt(5)$ and $b=1$?

Comment: I think the second equation you got should have no $x_3$ in it, and the coefficient in the last one should be $a^2-3$ not $a^2-5$...

Comment: @LukasArvidsson Yes, $(a,b) = (\sqrt{5},1)$ will do fine. There are other values as well (lots for $b$ but only $\pm \sqrt{5}$ for $a$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
& \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & a & 1 & 0 \\
1 & a+1 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 3a+2 & a^2 & b \\
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_2 \gets R_2-R_1} &
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & a & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 3a+2 & a^2 & b \\
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_3 \gets R_3-3R_1} &
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & a & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & a^2-3 & b \\
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_3 \gets R_3-2R_2} &
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & a & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a^2-3 & b \\
\end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_1 \gets R_1-aR_2} &
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a^2-3 & b \\
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

We conclude that:

- A unique solution exists whenever $a^2-3 \neq 0$, i.e., when $a \not\in \{\pm \sqrt{3}\}$.  The solution is $(\tfrac{-b}{a^2-3},0,\tfrac{b}{a^2-3})$ in this case.
- No solutions exist if and only if $a^2-3=0$ and $b \neq 0$.  In this case, the 3-rd row is $(0\ 0\ 0\ b)$ with $b \neq 0$, which is inconsistent.
- An infinite number of solutions exist if and only if $a^3-3=0$ and $b=0$.  In this case, the 3-rd row is $(0\ 0\ 0\ 0)$, which is a homogeneous system of linear equations with rank 2, so has a non-trivial null space.